# Kafka Spout Reading same message multiple times

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

If I increase the parallelism of a Kafka spout in my storm topology, how can I stop it from reading the same message in a topic multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Storm's Kafka spout persists consumer offsets to Zookeeper, so as long as you don't clear your Zookeeper store then it shouldn't read the same message more than once. If you are seeing a message being read multiple times, perhaps check that offsets are being persisted to your zookeeper instance?

I think that by default when running locally, the Kafka spout starts its own local Zookeeper instance (separate from Kafka's Zookeeper), which may have its state reset each time you restart the topology.

Answer (score 0):

you should check if the message is getting acknowledged properly. If not then the spout will treat it as failed and will reply the message.

Comment: addition to this answer. we also had the same problem by digging in we found that tuples take more time to process specified in `MessageTimeoutSecs`. So by increasing the value of `MessageTimeoutSecs` solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it is inflow from kafka into storm, then please share more information.

If data flow is out from storm to kafka:

then just check your TopologyBuilder in your code.

It **should not** be allGrouping, if yes then change it to shuffleGrouping

Example:

```
    builder.setBolt("OUTPUTBOLT", new OutBoundBolt(boltConfig), 4)
            .allGrouping("previous_bolt"); // this is wrong change it to
                                            // shuffleGrouping
```

All grouping: The stream is replicated across all the bolt's tasks. Use this grouping with care.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify consumer group. Once specified Kafka will give only the next message to any of your spouts. All spouts should belong to same consumer group.

While creating a consumer please specify following property

props.put("group.id", a_groupId);

Comment: I am using Trident Kafka Spout, I am not clear on how to add in this setting! Can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

If your kafka spout is Opeque then you need to topology.max.spout.pending<10
because "pending means the tuple has not been acked or failed yet" so, if there is no more tuple for each batch and less then the pending count, spout trying to reach max spout pending size.

You can handle this problem by using Transactional Spout if your needs meet.